# Laravel 5.2 - Array not being passed

Tags: arrays, laravel-5, view

I have a function in a method (Customer):

```
public function getAll() {
      $values = DB::table('customers')->orderBy('company','asc')->where('company','<>','')->get();
       return $values;
   }
```

which is called from a route:

```
Route::get('/customers', function(){
    $cust = new \App\Customer();
    $customers = $cust->getAll();
    //dd($customers);
    return view('customers.index')->with(compact('customers') );
});
```

If I check with dd I get an array of the customers.

In the view I have

```
@foreach($customers as $item)
<tr>
<td>{{ $item->customer }}</td>
<td>{{ $item->address }}</td>
<td>{{ $item->city }}</td>
<td>{{ $item->postcode }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

but I am getting

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$customer
```

Help! I have tried everything...

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use both `with` and `compact`.
Just one of them is enough, try this one:

```
Route::get('/customers', function(){
    $customers = \App\Customer::all();
    return view('customers.index', compact('customers'));
});
```

Comment: I changed the line in the route as suggested but I still have exactly the same error - Undefined property: stdClass::$customer